# When a excel column is filtered by a button, my rows should be updated. The update is about inserting values into visible cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So basically what I want is that when I filter a column, that all visible cells get a formula. The `=SUM` formula to be exactly, but the first visible cell should get the value of 1. The `SUM` formula sums up the first visible cell above the active cell, in this case the first cell with a formula should be the cell under the cell with the value 1.

The cell with the value of 1 is in the F column even as the cells with the formulas so for example: i filtered the cells F6,F9,F23. F6 should contain a 1, and F9 should contain `=SUM(F6,E6)` for F23 it must be `=(F9,E9)`.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub setValue()

Dim test As String
Dim rngCell As Excel.Range
Dim rngVisible As Excel.Range

gantCell = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
calcCell = gantCell - 3
Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [F5], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Worksheets("Gantt Chart").Cells(gantCell, 6).Value = "1"
gantCellNext = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
i = formCell
test = "F" & i
'MsgBox Lastrow
'MsgBox test
Sheets("Calculatie").Cells(calcCell, 2).Copy
For Each cell In Range(test).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Sheets("Gantt Chart").Range(test & ":F35").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=SUM(F" & activeCell.Row - 1 & "+" & "E" & activeCell.Row - 1 & ")"

Next

End Sub
```

Sorry if my English isn't that good, please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself, heres the code.

```
Sub setValue()

Dim test As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim ling As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim bol As Boolean

bol = False
GantCell = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
calcCell = GantCell - 3
formCell = GantCell + 1
Lastrow = Cells.Find("*", [F5], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Worksheets("Gantt Chart").Cells(GantCell, 6).Value = "1"
gantCellNext = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
i = formCell
test = "F" & i
l = "F" & GantCell
Range(l).Activate
Set rRng = activeCell

For Each rCell In Range(l & ":F35").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
ling = "F" & rCell.Row
'MsgBox ling
If bol = True Then
Set rRng = activeCell
rCell.Value = "=SUM(F" & rRng.Row & ":" & "E" & rRng.Row & ")"
Set rRng = Range(ling)
rRng.Select
ElseIf bol = False Then
Worksheets("Gantt Chart").Cells(GantCell, 6).Value = "1"
bol = True
End If
Next rCell


End Sub
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

This may be oversimplifying your problem, but have you looked at the `SUBTOTAL` function and using the constant that ignores hidden values (in your case `SUBTOTAL(109,range)`)?

Take a look at the documentation on the SUBTOTAL function here - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx